# Ruby fails after installing custom cartridge for OpenShift

Tags: ruby, openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge

So I am trying to install a custom cartridge that has python3.5 https://github.com/Praisebetoscience/openshift-cartridge-python-3.5

The command I'm running is:

```
rhc app create bot nodejs-0.10 http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/github/Praisebetoscience/openshift-cartridge-python-3.5
```

However after instalation of the cartridge completes ruby crashes with a strange error. I'm not really familiar with ruby and I'm not sure why this is coming from core library. Do you know what is causing that?

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `eval': (erb):1: syntax error, unexpecte
d tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
...    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Tim...
...                               ^
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `result'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/highline_ext
ensions.rb:48:in `say'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/helpers.rb:3
21:in `error'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/command_runn
er.rb:96:in `rescue in run!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/command_runn
er.rb:71:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/d
elegates.rb:12:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in
 `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/bin/rhc:20:in `<top
(required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: can you verify what versions of ruby and rhc you are running?  ruby -v, and rhc --version

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
rhc 1.38.4

Comment: Hmm, i got a different error, i tried with 1.9.3 and got a 504 error (which is weird), then i tried with 2.1 and basically the cartridge failed to install/start due to some path issues with the cartridge.  Can you try a newer version of ruby like 2.0?

Comment: I had the 504 after a retry it fixed. Tried with 2.3 ruby however I was getting another error which was fixed by switching to 1.9 the recommended version.

Comment: Tried with Ruby 2.0 and I got the same error.